# Google Script to save google form data to google doc

Tags: templates, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am unable to fetch data and pass it on to google doc via google script.

I am able to make a copy of the file as intended but the file doesnt have any data in it.

my code is as follows :

```
   function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
var timestamp = e.value[0];
 var Emailaddress = e.value[1];
 var Confidential = e.value3[2];
 var Name = e.value[3];

var docTempleteId = "1EqkL33juy9kdcEmiCCPi0B-Wm9cPy5q0xLkyo3qz-HE";
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(docTempleteId); 


  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1T8LdNSAQmT00yKmkx4cY-JQi6R3v2HLE")
  var copy = file.makeCopy(Name , folder); 


  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 

 var body = doc.getBody(); 

 body.replaceText("{{Name}}",Name)

doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

Please advise what is wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Is there any error message you're getting? That would make troubleshooting a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that it is not `e.value[1]` it's `e.values[1]`

I did this way and it works okay.

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var Name=e.values[5];
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById("id"); 
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("id");
  var copy=file.makeCopy(Name,folder); 
  var doc=DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  var body=doc.getBody(); 
  body.replaceText("{{Name}}",Name)
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

The file was created and copied to the correct folder and contained the correct data with the appropriate filename.

[Form Submit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)